I'm trying to select and click on one of three radio button using xpath and am having no luck. Any code suggestions?
HTML:
<input class="PrivateSwitchBase-input css-1m9pwf3" type="radio" data-testid="person-select-radio-1" aria-label="1 person" value="" checked="" name="mui-48">  

<input class="PrivateSwitchBase-input css-1m9pwf3" type="radio" data-testid="person-select-radio-2" aria-label="2 person" value="" checked="" name="mui-48">  

<input class="PrivateSwitchBase-input css-1m9pwf3" type="radio" data-testid="person-select-radio-3" aria-label="3 person" value="" checked="" name="mui-48">  

<input class="PrivateSwitchBase-input css-1m9pwf3" type="radio" data-testid="person-select-radio-4" aria-label="4 person" value="" checked="" name="mui-48">  

Code:
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//*input[@id='person-select-radio-4']")))

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//*[contains(text(),'person-select-radio-4')]")))

Neither work and time out

The first one doesn't work because it's looking for the id attribute, and those html elements do not have an id attribute.  Why did you think that would work?

First XPATH doesn't work because <input> doesn't have id.
Second XPATH doesn't work because 'person-select-radio-4' is not in text in <input...>text</input>
You have to use data-testid
'//input[@data-testid="person-select-radio-4"]'

or aria-label
'//input[@aria-label="4 person"]'


If there is no other inputs then you can use index [4] in XPATH to get 4th item
(XPATH starts at 1, not 0)
'//input[4]'

Of course you can use other function to get all inputs (as list of elements) and later use [-1] to get last element from list
all_items = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//input')
item = all_items[-1]


Full working code with example HTML directly in code.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# ---

import selenium
print('Selenium:', selenium.__version__)

# ---

#driver = webdriver.Chrome()    # the newest Selenium can download driver automatically
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

html = """
<input class="PrivateSwitchBase-input css-1m9pwf3" type="radio" data-testid="person-select-radio-1" aria-label="1 person" value="" checked="" name="mui-48">  
<input class="PrivateSwitchBase-input css-1m9pwf3" type="radio" data-testid="person-select-radio-2" aria-label="2 person" value="" checked="" name="mui-48">  
<input class="PrivateSwitchBase-input css-1m9pwf3" type="radio" data-testid="person-select-radio-3" aria-label="3 person" value="" checked="" name="mui-48">  
<input class="PrivateSwitchBase-input css-1m9pwf3" type="radio" data-testid="person-select-radio-4" aria-label="4 person" value="" checked="" name="mui-48"> 
"""

driver.get("data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + html)

# ---

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

print('\n--- version 1 ---\n')

item = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//input[@data-testid="person-select-radio-4"]')))
print(item)
print('data-testid:', item.get_attribute('data-testid'))
print('aria-label :', item.get_attribute('aria-label'))

print('\n--- version 2 ---\n')

item = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//input[@aria-label="4 person"]')))
print(item) 
print('data-testid:', item.get_attribute('data-testid'))
print('aria-label :', item.get_attribute('aria-label'))

print('\n--- version 3 ---\n')

item = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//input[4]')))
print(item) 
print('data-testid:', item.get_attribute('data-testid'))
print('aria-label :', item.get_attribute('aria-label'))

print('\n--- version 4 ---\n')

all_items = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//input')
item = all_items[-1]
print(item) 
print('data-testid:', item.get_attribute('data-testid'))
print('aria-label :', item.get_attribute('aria-label'))

driver.close()

